# Firebase database StartAt Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to make queries on my firebase database

The structure of my current database is as follows

[image: Database Img]

The query is as follows (works fine):

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/'+id).orderByValue().endAt(7000).once('value').then(......
```

To avoid having to download all the data from the node and process the query on the client, I must create the rules. For now I have this:

```
"users": {
     "$id": {
         ".indexOn": ".value"
     }
}
```

My question is: with this rule, my query will only download what is necessary or do I have to add something else like ".indexOn": ".value> 7000" to be efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define both the index and the query on the level in the JSON where you want to execute them. Since you want to query users on their value, the index looks like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       ".indexOn": ".value"
     }
  }
}
```

So this defines an index on `/users`, where you can then order/filter its child nodes on their value.

Then you can query it with:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/users')
  .orderByValue()
  .endAt(7000)
  .once('value')
  .then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.key+": "+snapshot.val());
    });
  })
```

If you want to make sure that no extra data is being read here, you can do two things

1. Look the JavaScript console, which will log explicitly when it's missing an index.
2. Look at the Web Socket tab in the Network console of your browser, where you can see exactly what data is being sent received by Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

No, just saying `.value` is enough.  In fact, what you're proposing isn't even value.  The entire range of child names will be indexed with `.value`.